# Error in training SGDClassifier about the target variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Error in using SGDClassifier the code details are

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42,max_iter=5, tol=1)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
```

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-46-87fa09f050da> in <module>
>       3 
>       4 sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42,max_iter=5, tol=1)
> ----> 5 sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
>
> //anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py
> ```
>
> in fit(self, X, y, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
>           711                          loss=self.loss, learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
>           712                          coef_init=coef_init, intercept_init=intercept_init,
>       --> 713                          sample_weight=sample_weight)
>           714 
>           715
>
> ```
> //anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py
> ```
>
> in _fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, coef_init,
>   intercept_init, sample_weight)
>           552 
>           553         self._partial_fit(X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, self.max_iter,
>       --> 554                           classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
>           555 
>           556         if (self.tol is not None and self.tol > -np.inf
>
> ```
> //anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py
> ```
>
> in _partial_fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, max_iter,
>   classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
>           516             raise ValueError(
>           517                 "The number of classes has to be greater than one;"
>       --> 518                 " got %d class" % n_classes)
>           519 
>           520         return self
>
> ```
> ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stackowerflow, You need to format your question, and make it more clear and readable please, For more help that How to ask Question follow the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems that your targets: y_train_5 has only one class. Your dataset must have at least 2 classes to perform classification. Check your data before training. len(set(y_train)) must be superior to 1.